# Wireless Mouse and Keyboard lag sporadically in Kubuntu 18.04. Not sure how to diagnose further

Tags: wireless, usb, keyboard, kubuntu, mouse

really sorry I know this is a super common question but I've searched the other answers and so far nothing seems to be very helpful, and/or I lack the knowledge to properly diagnose the issue further and give more relevant information.

Here is the information I do have:

I have [this USB extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NH13UFQ) plugged into a USB 3 port in the back of my machine.

I have [this USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KZEAR9A) plugged into that. I have to use this setup because this new Kubuntu machine is kept in the closet as a media and cloud server.

I have [this mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DHECXA) plugged into one of the ports on the hub.

I have [this keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PIMIUPW) plugged into one of the ports on the hub.

Nothing else is plugged into the hub.

Also the widget on this website directed me to run a script when I put the wireless tag in. Here are the results in a pastebin since posting them here goes over the character count: https://pastebin.com/unAxP72Q

The lagging is sporadic. It comes and goes on both the mouse and the keyboard (though it seems the keyboard more so). It's like it's intermittently picking up signal or something. I'm sitting right next to the hub and I have no problem when in a Windows installation.

when it starts messing up I switch to a wired keyboard and a wired mouse which I plug into the same hub. The cord on the keyboard is messed up so after awhile I'll get frustrated with it acting janky when I shift the cord on my lap or something, and then I'll check back and see if the wireless keyboard is working again, and sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't. I can't seem to find any particular rhyme or reason to it.

I have checked the batteries and that is not the issue, as I can tell due to the fact that it works fine in Windows etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same situation here, without a solution yet.

Comment: I did have the same problem with a logitech wireless keyboard.
It did not work well (too much lag) if plugged directly in a usb port of the PC.
But once plugged in my usb hub it did work without problem. No lag any more.
No idea why.